# date validation in classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, vbscript

date validation in classic asp

i am new in classic asp and having problem in validating the date

```
dim Day,Month,Year,FullDate
Day = "01"
Month = "20"
Year = "2012"
FullDate = Month + "/" + Day + "/" + Year

document.write FullDate
document.write IsDate(FullDate)
document.write IsDate(CDate(FullDate))
document.write IsDate(20/01/2012)
```

output :

```
20/01/2012
true true false
```

Comment: Is it a typo that you don't have the last date in quotes?

Comment: no typo here , IsDate(mm/dd/yyyy) my question is why there is TRUE in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking why `document.write IsDate(20/01/2012)` doesn't write `true` the reason is because you've asked the computer to do division, then evaluate that as a date.

`20/01 = 20 => 20/2012 ~= 0.01`

`IsDate(0.01) => false`

If you really want to test what you've got try this instead (small tweak)

```
Your: document.write IsDate(20/01/2012)
Mine: document.write IsDate("20/01/2012")
```

---

Also, just for clarification http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Some countries use

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

and some places use

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

and that's why the International Standards Organization suggests you do things with least specificity to most specificity:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ffffffffffff
```

Notice that's Years -> Months (which month is more specific than which year) -> Days (which day an event occurs on is helpful) -> Hours (don't be late!) -> Minutes (saved by the bell?) -> Seconds (Now you have some idea when it happened) -> fractions of a second (Olympic Swimming!!)

Years are rather non-specific. Lots of things happen in one year. So those should always parse first. The ISO way is the preferred way to pass Date information, and when the year does not come first, the system tries to guess intelligently. Since some parts of the world do `dmy` and some do `mdy` and since only one of your starting two numbers is over 12, it assumes you mean `dmy` instead of `mdy`. No WTF here.

---

For the record, here are a list of countries which predominantly put the month first as a matter of tradition in `mdy` format (excluding ISO formatting which is not tradition, but science)

- Belize
- Federated States of Micronesia
- Palau
- United States of America

---

And finally if you want to write a function that will try and reparse the date for you:

Consider that people tend to break the date with either spaces, periods, hyphens or slashes, they may write it as "20120817" or they may include the time as well. There may be a T in the middle, and it may have a Z at the end.

Sample inputs: (and the date they represent)

```
2011-08-17 (august 17th)
2011-08-01 (august 1st or jan 8th?)
08-01-2011 (august 1st or jan 8th?)
08-17-2011 (august 17th)
17-08-2011 (august 17th)
2011-17-08 (I've never seen this ever)

2011/08/17 (august 17th)
2011.08.01 (august 1st or jan 8th?)
08\01\2011 (august 1st or jan 8th?)
08-17-2011 (august 17th)
17 08 2011 (august 17th)
```

As you can see, there's a fair bit of parsing that has to happen here, and that's to assume that they have a 10 digit string and that that 10 digits is a date. Here are some other date formats:

```
08-01-12   (was that January 8th, 2012 or January 12th, 2008 or August 1st, 2012 ...)
15-03-13   (ok, so we have found the month is March, but the other two?)
1-1-1
8-8-8      (these two are easy, but which rule do they match?)
```

And then you have to parse

```
20120817
20121708
20120801
01082012
08172012
```

So as you can see, parsing the function *seems* easy but there's a lot to consider, and this is JUST dates. Want to let's talk about times next?

```
201208171311   -> 2012-08-17 13:11    (1:11 PM)
20120817T1311  -> 2012-08-17 13:11    (1:11 PM)
20120817T0111P -> 2012-08-17 01:11 PM
```

Comment: FullDate = 20/01/2012, here month is 20 that is not correct , response should be false

Comment: @VijayShah see if that makes more sense for you.

Comment: To add to what @jcolebrand said, here is a link with a function that you can use to normalize your date formats http://p2p.wrox.com/classic-asp-professional/41451-isdate-validation-problem.html#post165295